# Tag for certain kinds of visual interface customization

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

I'm wondering how to tag [How do I display line numbers in emacs (not in the mode line)?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/278/how-do-i-display-line-numbers-in-emacs-not-in-the-mode-line)

It was originally tagged [customization](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customization), but that's a really bad tag name. It can easily be confused with Emacs's framework for defining and setting configuration settings (for which I propose the tag name [customize](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customize), but even that is going to be heavily misused). And it's overly broad: pretty much every question can be considered to be customizing Emacs in some way.

Linum mode is documented in the [“Minor Modes”](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minor-Modes.html#Minor-Modes) section of the manual, in the “Modes” chapter. But [modes](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modes) or [minor-modes](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minor-modes) wouldn't do, because “show line numbers” isn't a question about minor modes, the fact that the answer uses a minor mode is an implementation detail. Under Emacs 23, that section was in the “Customization” chapter, but that too is not a good tag name.

So what tag can we use to categorize this kind of visual interface customization when editing or viewing files?

Comment: Interface or visual-interface is the best I can think of.

Comment: The tag [tag:line-numbers] is appropriate. There are lots of Stack Overflow and help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org questions about indicating the current line number, displaying line numbers, etc. Using tag [tag:line-numbers] does not preclude also using tags about particular display aspects, to indicate better what is involved ([tag:mode-line], [tag:margin], etc.).